# Exploded multidimensional array from long string

Tags: php, arrays, string, multidimensional-array, explode

I have a string:

```
Some text1    Info about text1     Numbers about text1  
Some text2    Info about text2     Numbers about text2  
Some text3    Info about text3     Numbers about text3
```

Every line is of course ending with a `\n`, and every text bit is separated with a `\t`. This is something I cannot change.

i.e. Some text1\tInfo about text1\tNumbers about text1\n

The string comes via a $_POST() and I then want to explode this so that i can save each part of each line in my DB.

My code:

```
$sigs = $_POST['allSigInput'];

$strings = explode ("\n", $sigs);
$sigCount = count($strings);

var_dump($strings);

foreach($strings as $string) {
    for($c=0; $c<=$sigCount; $c++) {
        ${'sigArr_'.$c} = explode ("\t", $string);
    }
}
```

This explodes the string just fine but var_dump(); for all $sigArr_# are the same, and the last array saved.

So all 3 outputs are the same:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => string 'Some Text3'
  1 => string 'Info about text3'
  2 => string 'Numbers about text3'
```

I would of course like the 3 arrays to contain info respectively to each line of text and be exploded so every bit of text separated by `\t`, is in an array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how you wish to store the data but I think you have an extra loop here.

```
foreach($strings as $string) {
    for($c=0; $c<=$sigCount; $c++) {
        ${'sigArr_'.$c} = explode ("\t", $string);
    }
}
```

Eighter use `foreach` or `for` in order the loop through `strings` array.

And your test condition in `for` loop is wrong

```
for($c=0; $c<=$sigCount; $c++)
```

should be

```
for($c=0; $c<$sigCount; $c++)
```

Say you wish to use the `for` loop, then your code becomes

```
//foreach($strings as $string) {
    for($c=0; $c<$sigCount; $c++) {
        ${'sigArr_'.$c} = explode ("\t", $strings[$c]);
    }
//}
```

Then you can see the output correcty with

```
var_dump($sigArr_0);
var_dump($sigArr_1);
```

Comment: Kind sir of the internet. you just made my day! Thank you very much!! I can't upvote since i don't have 15 reputition yet, but i will do that later! I'm one big smile now! thank you!

Comment: you're welcome:] you can accept the answer if you think it is correct (would be much appreciated:])